# How to prove language L is not regular? L = {a^3^k | k element N} is subset of {a,b}*

Tags: subset, dfa

L = {a^3^k | k element N} is subset of {a,b}*

I have to prove that the language L is not regular, but I don't know what the subset means for the proof.

{a^3^k | k element N} should be regular because I can draw a DFA and I also can draw a DFA of {a, b}.

[image]

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).  Just keep in mind that this question should only be posted on one SE site, so if you wanted to migrate it, either delete this question first, or flag "Other" and describe to a moderator where you want to migrate it to.

Comment: The first DFA does not recognize a^3^k. It recognizes a^(3k). And the part about the subset - just forget that. It's useless here and in the way it's put it's even misleading, because the language will never contain any b. It's true what it says, but that doesn't help you at all. The problem was formulated in a bad style, that's all.

Comment: Oh, you are right, my DFA does not match the language and there is no DFA for a^3^k. But now I have to prove that the DFA does not exist ...

Comment: @jannnik to proof DFA don't exists -proof it is not a regular language using pumping lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not regular. In fact a very good rule of thumb to tell at a glance is if the language is trying to count characters in a non-repeatable fashion.

You can't count with a single regular expression a sequence like 1, 3, 9, 27 while making sure all the other counts fail, you need something repeatable like `\d{5}` in normal regex notation.

I'll leave the proof up to you since this is obviously homework, just clarifying the misconception that this is regular because you can draw the first two elements. Sure you can, but you can't draw the generic term in a general way!

Comment: I think I understand your "rule of thumb". But I don't understand how to prove it. Is it possible to prove it with the pumping lemma?

Comment: I'm not very experienced in using the pumping lemma for a formal proof, but I understand the standard-pumping-lemma-expample with a^n b^n.

By the way: no homework but preparation for an exam (it's the exercise from an old exam)

Comment: It's relatively trivial to prove using the pumping lemma. You need `xpy`, so starting from k=1 you have `(a)(a)(a)`. That would imply that pumping `p` once is also in the language, ie `(a)(aa)(a)` but that's not the case. And there's no other way to split `aaa` up so the proof is done. That's what I remember from college anyway, it's been a while. This very clearly shows how limited regular expressions are, any kind of special counting will most likely fail.